# Bind parameter to variable in Oracle report PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create an Oracle report using date parameters. I know how to add parameters to an Oracle report, but I can't figure out how to bind it to a variable in the PL/SQL query that drives the report. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parameter is named MY_PARAM1 then you can reference it in the report SQL like this:

```
select a, b, c
from my_table
where col1 = :my_param1
```